# Como soluciono el error 403 Forbidden de mi formulario

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

el Xampp y MySql estan activos pero cuando quiero entrar a mi formulario de php me tira el error de la foto. como lo puedo solucionar? (el PhpMyAdmin se puede ver)

Reinstale el xampp y el mySql, los videos en yt me salen para phpMyAdmin pero no me da una solucion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La URL está mal formada. Debe tener la forma `http://localhost/ruta/a/tu/script.php` o, si no usas el puerto default, quizás: `http://localhost:8080/ruta/a/tu/script.php` (dónde 8080 es el puerto). La `/ruta/a/tu/script` no es una ruta del disco duro, es decir, no puede tener esta forma `c:\x\y`, sino es la ruta dentro del servidor web.